# Accessing Parent Namespace in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

I've got a scenario like the following:

```
class criterion 
{
// stuff about criteria...
};
namespace hex {

     class criterion : public criterion //does not compile
     {                                  //This should inherit from the
     //A hex specific criterion         //criterion class in the global namespace
     };

};
```

My question is -- how does one inherit from a class in a namspace which is the parent of another namespace?

Billy3

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start with "::"

For example

```
class criterion : public ::criterion {};
```

Answer (score 20):

You need to specify the namespace, in this case the global one:

```
 class criterion : public ::criterion
```

Note that c++ doesn't specify any means of navigating namespaces as if they were a tree. For example, you can't specify the the "parent" namespace using ".." or any other shorthand - you have to use its name.

Answer (score 9):

Simplified basic C++ namespace rules are:

- You can access anything in parent namespace path without specifying namespace.
- You can access anything in child namespace path by specifying only relative path.
- Everything else requires full namespace specifications.

Answer (score 4):

This compiles for me, basically just explicitly show in what namespace the parent class is:

```
class A
{};
namespace B {
    class A : public ::A
    {};
    namespace C {
        class A : public B::A
        {};
    }
};
```