# Strange code... Can someone explain me this

Tags: c++, inheritance, namespaces

Hi I am switching to C++ from C. While reading http://www.gotw.ca/publications/xc++.htm I see this code block.

```
const int i = 1;
const int j = 2;
struct x
{
   int x;
};
namespace y
{
   int i[i];
   int j = j;
   x x;
   int y::y = x.x;
};
```

And I am totally confused about this specially in `namespace y` section.
Please explain me the behavior of this code and use of namespace. Also I read somewhere that bad use of namespace leading to violating fundamentals of `inheritance`. Please give me some examples of using namespace brilliantly.

Comment: Does this code even compile?

Comment: @leppie. I don`t know. In book they wrote it like that and marked this as a working example...

Comment: Simplified, `namespace y` says "everything contained inside my braces needs to be prefixed by `y::` to be found by the compiler" It's a way to avoid naming conflicts, `x::x` is not the same as `y::x`, without namespaces both would be named `x`.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson... Does bad use of namespace leads to violating fundamentals of `inheritance`??

Comment: The last line looks suspiciously non compiling though.

Comment: @Krishna I'm not sure what that statement would refer to actually, so can't say yes or no. Leaning towards no though :) Abuse of any any language feature can lead to bad code, but I can't see why namespaces would be worse than any other feature when it comes to inheritance.

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Comment: This is terrible. First, it does not compile, you cannot explicitly declare `y::y`. Then `int i[i]` does happen to work, because the compiler is desperately looking for a `int const`, but `int j = j` is undefined behavior. `int y = x.x` would be undefined behavior as well, because `x.x` is not default constructed.

Comment: Have you tried this in a compiler? On ideone.com? Have you read the part of the book that comes with the code? And to continue the trend: Should we bother to provide you an answer?

Comment: @kfsone.. It depends whether you want to give answer or not... Well I read the book properly and when I didn`t get this thing I came here. It is written like a trick..

Comment: You have posted the code partially it seems, can you please give the page number of the referred book ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is using some horribly obfuscated code to illustrate a point about the scope of names. From C++11 §3.3.6 [basic.scope.namespace] p1:

> ... A namespace member name has namespace scope. Its potential scope includes its namespace from the name’s point of declaration (3.3.2) onwards ...

*point of declaration* is defined in §3.3.2 [basic.scope.pdecl] p1:

> The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below.

So it is possible to use e.g. the name `i` from an outer scope in the initializer of something named `i` in an inner scope. The code in question:

```
const int i = 1;
const int j = 2;
struct x
{
   int x;
};

namespace y
{
   int i[i];
   int j = j;
   x x;
   int y::y = x.x;
}
```

declares:

- `y::i` as an array of 1 `int` that will be implicitly zeroed (since all static storage duration objects are zero-initialized if they have no explicit initializer),
- `y::j` as an `int` with initial value 2,
- `y::x` as struct of type `::x` that will be implicitly zeroed, and
- `y::y` is an invalid name. If it was simply `y`, it *would be* an `int` with initial value 0, since its initializer `y::x.x` is implicitly zero-initialized.

[Here's a demo (with `y::y` changed to `y`) at Coliru.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=f703c9fc444d7943516bef5a3e05f9c7-c944ac6b0eed3bfc48b1f78a894f6965)

NOTE: DO NOT EVER WRITE CODE LIKE THIS. The only time using this feature of names even borders on being acceptable is for member initializers in a class constructor. If you do this anywhere else, I will find you. And I will make you pay.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is some problem with your code. The int y::y = x.x; section is wrong as there is no y previous to this and so this statement needs some correction. I am trying to give some basic info about namespace and its usage, hope it helps. 
The main purpose of namespaces is to logically group functionality without the need of long names and the option for handy usage via "using". You can also use same name over different namespaces

```
namespace Color
{
    class Add {};
    class Multiply {};
};

namespace Dimension
{
    class Add {};
    class Multiply {};
};
```

So you can use the same class name Add, Multiply under two namespaces and one thing which you have to remember is that use namespaces only when required otherwise you will spam the global namespace "std" unknowingly which is not conventional.

For using namespace with inheritance you can search for articles in stack over flow and definitely you will get some. Ex: [Accessing Parent Namespace in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139430/accessing-parent-namespace-in-c)

Comment: I would have understood this question as "why does this code use namespace and what for" rather than "what is a namespace and its purpose"

Answer (score 0):

```
int i[i];  //line 1
```

It creates an int array of size 1, as the index i is a constant initialized to 1

```
int j = j; //line 2
```

It declares and initilizes a variable j to 2(value of constant j) in a namespace y

```
x x;   //line 3
```

It creates a structure variable x of type struct x ( **Note: The structure variable x is different from the int x present inside the structure x, int x is a member of structure x**

```
int y::y = x.x;  //line 4
```

This is syntactically wrong, there is no need to qualify int y with namespace('y'), as it is already present in the namespaace y, So the statement should be

```
int y = x.x
```

where x.x represents accessing the data member (int x) of structure variable x created in the line 3

**Namespace example**  Have a look on this example,it helps you to understand namespaces clearly. Refer the link for more examples [link]http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/

```
   #include <iostream>
using namespace std;

namespace first
{
  int x = 5;
  int y = 10;
}

namespace second
{
  double x = 3.1416;
  double y = 2.7183;
}

int main () {
  using namespace first;
  cout << x << endl;
  cout << y << endl;
  cout << second::x << endl;
  cout << second::y << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

**//Output**
5
10
3.1416
2.7183

```
          ......Hope it helps you....:)
```